# Web app's external library went wrong after published

Tags: reactjs

When I made a webapp in my localhost using an external library everything works fine. 
But when I publish it on Github pages, It **works on Github** but my local version now has an error:

```
vanilla-tilt.js:1 ---  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

It happens on any external library with this same error, and the part using the library not working.
I'm using React and attached the library inside the **body** tag in the index.html
Anything I can do to solve it?. 
Thank you.